# how to not get object ID when calling a function that was defined inside a class

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, object

Here is my code:

```
#define class 'robot'
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, name, color, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.weight = weight
    def introduce_self(name):
        print("Hello world, I am a robot! My name is", name)

#instantiate 2 'robot' objects
r1 = Robot('tom', 'red', 30)
r2 = Robot('jerry', "blue", 40)

r1.introduce_self()
r2.introduce_self()
```

I expect the result to look like this:

```
Hello world, I am a robot! My name is tom
Hello world, I am a robot! My name is jerry
```

Instead I get this:

```
Hello world, I am a robot! My name is <__main__.Robot object at 0x0000013704E2FFD0>
Hello world, I am a robot! My name is <__main__.Robot object at 0x0000013704E2FF10>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature is incorrect. For instance methods the first argument is the object itself (usually named `self`):

```
def introduce_self(self):
    print("Hello world, I am a robot! My name is", self.name)
```